# Separate columns separated by semicolan in c++

Tags: c++, math

I have a set of points and they are separated by a semicolon. I need to select the all points in column 2 that are greater than 0 and their corresponding column1 and column3 points. Below is my input and code. I'm unable separate columns 2 and 3. Could you kindly help me.

My input file:

```
500; 600; 200
100; -200; 300
200; -500; 850
420; 350; 650
```

My code is as below

```
ifstream inputFile("inputfile.txt");

string line;
float column1, column2, column3;

vector <float> column1Vector;
vector <float> column2Vector;
vector <float> column3Vector;

while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> column1 >> column2 >> column3;
    if (column2 > 0)
    {
        column1Vector.push_back(column1);
        column2Vector.push_back(column2);
        column3Vector.push_back(column3);
    }
}
inputFile.close();
```

My output should be as follows:

```
500; 600; 200
420; 350; 650
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I recommend you see each line as a single *record*, and use *structures* to store the data from each line.

Comment: Just replace `,` with `;`.  A CSV and a SSV are the same thing.

Comment: in your code you're assuming that the file is well formatted, without garbage. I'd think about what happens if one line has only two entries or if an entry is text instead of numbers.